# How to bind repeater data of product details to transaction details?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can't seem to figure out how to bind the data that I got from a stored procedure to transactions details when I click on "Add To Cart" button. I am using repeater control to show all the product details from the stored procedure. So for example when I click on button i want the name of the brand to appear in a label. My concern is that it will add everything because of that repeater.

HTML CODE
`code here`https://pastebin.com/CERvTLfk

Code behind it
`code here`https://pastebin.com/nYnv7RmG

Sorry If my explanation is confusing. Maybe the pictures might help.

[HTML PAGE PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRQEM.jpg)

[DATA TABLE PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC6mH.jpg)

Comment: I guess better to use the ItemCommand event.
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand

Comment: I used this but now its not giving me the data that I click, instead it gives me the last data from the repeater control                                                   
       protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptrProducts.Items)
            {
                lblProduct.Text = ((DataBoundLiteralControl)item.Controls[0]).Text;
                                
            }
        }